# o(h) term in birth-death process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, birth-death-process

This is from the note
[image]

I have two questions.

1. Since $o(h)$ represents the probability of 2 birth and 1 death, 3 birth and 2 death, etc, why it still says $P(|X(t+h)-X(t)|>1)=o(h)$? shouldn't it be $P(|X(t+h)-X(t)|=1)=o(h)$?
2. how to get the equation 13 from equation 12?

Comment: To get (13) from (12), the idea is that for small $h$, $h^2\ll h$. In other words, as $h\to 0$, $h^2$ is negligibly small compared to $h$ (and similarly for $h^3$, $h^4$, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what does $o(h)$ (*it is a class of functions*, called [Landau or Big- O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics)) actually mean? Generally it means for a function $f\in o(g)$ that we have
$$
{\displaystyle \lim _{x\to a}\left|{\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}}\right|=0}
$$ As an example, take a differentiable function $f$, then we have for $h\to0$ the following 
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+o(h)
$$
this means, that the approximation error goes faster than linear to $0$.

**Your $2$nd question** was already answered by @Math1000, for completeness:

Since we investigate the behavior of $h$ close to $0$, we indeed have 
$$
h^2\ll h \text{ respectively for }n\geq2: h^n\ll h
$$ 
so for $h\to0$, all higher powers $h^n$ are of neglectable magnitude compared to $h$ and therefore we get 
$$
(\lambda_ih)(1-h(\lambda_i+\mu_i)+\ldots)+o(h)=\lambda_ih+o(h)
$$
**Your $1$st question**:

The expression
$$
P(|X(t+h)-X(t)|>1|X(t)=i)=o(h)
$$
means, that for sufficient small h  ($\to 0$), the probability that there occurs  a jump in each direction larger of magnitude larger than $1$ is converging to $0$ faster than linear and for very small $h$ neglectable.

The bottom line is, that a Birth-Death process only jumps by $\pm1$ into the next state.